# `translate_uri_dashes` not working codeigniter route

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i already tried this code in route file but it not convert `_` to `-` by default

```
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route['stock/upload_stock'] = 'stock/upload_stockt';
```

Answer (score 6):

**CodeIgniter 3** provides a nice way for it ,There is a route

`$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = false;`

which is by default set to false, but if you set it to true, you can name your controllers and controller methods using the underscores (_s) and can call them using dashes (-s).

For example you have a controller named `Company`, and inside your Controller you have a method called `about_us`, now you can call it both the ways `/company/about_us` and `company/about-us` , when your `$route['translate_uri_dashes']` is set to true.

So, try making your route as below

```
$route['stock/upload-stock'] = 'stock/upload_stock';
```

Comment: i have too many methods so i cant route every method to get - dash

Comment: You just don't add any routes as codeigniter will handle your `dashes` to underscore

Comment: Sounds Good...If it helped you can accept it as answer to help others facing same issue